# ng-model not populating select

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

This is my object,

```
$scope.addresses = [
        {
            "addressLine1": "150 Address",
            "addressLine2": "LONDON",
            "addressLine3": "",
            "addressLine4": "EC00 00X"
        },
        {
            "addressLine1": "152 Address",
            "addressLine2": "LONDON",
            "addressLine3": "",
            "addressLine4": "EC00 00X"
        },
        {
            "addressLine1": "154 Address",
            "addressLine2": "LONDON",
            "addressLine3": "",
            "addressLine4": "EC00 00X"
        }
    ];
```

This is my select HTML

```
<select  ng-model="model.addressChoice" ng-options="(a.addressLine1+ ', '+ a.addressLine2+ ', '+ a.addressLine3+ ', '+ a.addressLine4) for a in addresses">
            <option value="" disabled selected>{{select.length}} Address's Found</option>
        </select>
```

I've found that when using `model.addressChoice = addresses[2]` it will populate the select field although should I use

```
mode.addressChoice = {
                "addressLine1": "154 Address",
                "addressLine2": "LONDON",
                "addressLine3": "",
                "addressLine4": "EC00 00X"
            }
```

This fails, why is that? I've set up a plunkr here as an example as well.

https://plnkr.co/edit/BtxMDP0mtJx4m7PTLD6B?p=preview

Comment: Remove " disabled selected " and try it

Comment: I think the value of your model should be an instance of your options (adresses) object or array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `disabled selected` inside `option` tag

```
    <select  
            ng-model="model.addressChoice" 
            ng-options="(a.addressLine1+ ', '+ a.addressLine2+ ', '+ a.addressLine3+ ', '+ a.addressLine4) for a in addresses">

            <option value="">{{select.length}} Address's Found</option>
 </select>
```

When loading selected " 3 Address's Found "

Answer (score 3):

It fails because you're creating another instance with this code:

```
        mode.addressChoice = {
            "addressLine1": "154 Address",
            "addressLine2": "LONDON",
            "addressLine3": "",
            "addressLine4": "EC00 00X"
        }
```

and "addresses" array, which setted in ng-options attribute, doesnt contains this elem. You should use only links to objects from "addresses" collection.

Comment: @Liably - you should mark this as the correct answer.